# Websocket handshake. From ws to wss

Tags: javascript, java, ssl, https, websocket

I am developing an app for some time and recently I attached to the app an SSL Certificate (it is not self-signed; it is signed by Comodo, so the problem can't occur from here). I implemented long ago a WebSocket endpoint on my Java Glassfish server and I'm using it with javascript. I have been using the WebSocket successfully via http until now, when I moved to https.

Let's have a look at the code snippets I use:

**Server Endpoint:**

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/chat", 
    encoders = ChatMessageEncoder.class, 
    decoders = ChatMessageDecoder.class)
public class ChatEndpoint {

@OnOpen
public void open(final Session session) {
    // stuff happenin'
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(final Session session) {
    // stuff happenin'    }

@OnError
public void onError(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("error");
}

@OnClose
public void onClose() {
}
}
```

**Client Connection:**

```
var wsocketPrivate;
function connectToChatserver() {
    var serviceLocation = 'wss://<ip>:8080/ws/chat';
    $rootScope.wsocketPrivate = new WebSocket(serviceLocation);
    $rootScope.wsocketPrivate.onmessage = onMessageReceived;
};
function onMessageReceived(evt) {
    console.log(evt)
};
connectToChatserver();
```

Not having activated ssl certificate and using `var serviceLocation = 'ws://<ip>:8080/ws/chat';` (ws instead of wss) works perfectly fine. When I moved to https, it asked for wss (the browser blocked my ws handshake because it wasn't secure) and moving to wss, the following error occurs:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://<ip>:8080/ws/chat' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you suggest some tests to find out more information?

Thank you,
Mihai

Comment: did you solve this ?? i'm kinda stuck in this too

Comment: Yes, check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found where the problem was. I was using an nginx front server as a proxy. The default configuration of that server was blocking my wss for some weird reason.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, can you please tell what additional configuration you add in nginx-server config file

Comment: If I can get Tyrus to do SSL programmatically, I can forsee I'm also going to have this problem. What's the config change?